# socket.volatile.emit from client side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am developing a simple application, with a node.js server, and an HTML5 client in browser. At the moment, I am using `socket.io` for the communication, because it seems to me that it should work in most cases: proxies, firewalls, etc. On the other hand, I find hard to now precisely what is going on, as a lot of things are automated, and as I did not find a comprehensive documentation. One other important point is that I am new to the Javascript/Node.js world.

In this particular question, I am trying to achieve a tight synchronisation between clients and a server, following an SNTP-like scheme. Therefore, I would like to drop any delayed packet. The `volatile` flag should allow me to do this, and I use it on to emit messages from the server, but it does not seem valid from the client side. Is it by design? Because I am using the stand-alone version on the client (no `require` or `browserify` here)?

index.html

```
<html>
    <body onload="init()">
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="calibration.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

calibration.js

```
var socket = io.connect();
function init() {
   socket.emit('test', 'ok');
   socket.volatile.emit('test-volatile', 'bad');
}
```

console log on page load

> socket.volatile is undefined

Is `volatile` pointless from the client side anyway? If not, is there a way to use it? Any pointer to documentation would be appreciated. At the moment, I am considering `engine.io` or `ws` `node.js` packages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think sending volatile messages from the client to the server is not supported yet.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/283

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/pull/821

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even late. (I was not authorised to answer myself, being new here.) 8 months later, socket.io documentation is still superficial... I am moving toward [Primus](http://primus.io) now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using socket.io-client to send a volatile emit from client to server. But, as I am sending the message right after the connection I had to use a setTimeout()

```
const socket = io( { autoConnect: false });

function init(){
    socket.open();

    setTimeout(() => {
        socket.volatile.emit('hello', 'world');
    }, 1000);
}
```